# Execution Timed Out problem on code wars.How to optimize the code

Tags: javascript, optimization

everyone.I was practicing on code wars and solving a problem aimed on prime numbers.I comleted it, but having submitted the program i get the message Execution Timed Out (12000 ms); Here is the program: `

```
function isPrime(number) {
  let counter = 0;
  for (let i=1;i<=number;i++){
    if (number % i == 0) {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  if (counter == 2) {
    return true
  } else return false
}


function getPrimes(start, finish) {
    let a = [];
  let b = [];
if (start == 0 && finish == 0) {
    return b;
}
if (start < finish) {
  for (let i=start;i<=finish;i++){
  a.push(i);
  }
 for (let j=0;j<a.length;j++)   {
    if (isPrime(a[j])) {
        b.push(a[j]);
    }
  }
  return b;
  } 
 
  else if (start > finish) {
  for (let i=finish;i<=start;i++){
  a.push(i);
  
  }
    for (let j=0;j<a.length;j++)    {
    if (isPrime(a[j])) {
        b.push(a[j]);
    }
  }
  return b;
  } 
}
```

`
There are two funcs, the first one returns true if the number is prime and false if not.
and the second one takes  start and finish like array borders and you need to return sorted array of prime numbers in these diapazon.I will be grateful for your help =)

Comment: diapazon (tuning fork)? Perhaps if you spelled out the code wars question more clearly your code attempt would make some sense - for instance ... how is your code even running? it's just two functions ... `getPrimes` is never called, therefore `isPrime` is never called

Comment: Also, your isPrime function is very inefficient ... better (yet still not the best) efficiency is to check that there are no factors in the range 2 ... square root of input number ... and return false immediately rather than continuing to check!

Comment: For a comparison, your code in my browser takes 45 seconds to check if `4294967311` is prime (which it is), and 45 seconds to test if `4294967312` is prime - which it isn't .... a more efficient algorithm takes less than 2ms to test `4294967311` and virtually no time to test `4294967312`